# How to connect two Android apps through to the same App Engine Datastore through Google Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

I want to create two Android applications that should be connected to a common Google App Engine Datastore. The two Android applications will have some App Engine based methods in common and some methods that are unique to each application.

Should I use separate App Engine modules for each app? This would probably require replicating all modules in both the apps and would unnecessarily increase the size of each app.

Can I just use different Android client ids and App Engine version numbers to connect the two Android apps to the same App Engine project through Endpoints? Would I need to replicate the entity definitions and methods for common entities in the two apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the same project with different versions or instances.

You could use a version as a web app and another as an android back-end for example, while both share the same datastore.